# React-Native, SafeAreaView iphone 8

Tags: react-native

Using React-Native's `SafeAreaView` on Iphone X works great, but once I switch to Iphone 8, the safe area on footer is still there, and the safe are suddenly becomes no help.

Any suggestions on what to do?

Comment: I made it work by changing some styles.

Answer (score 0):

For the fastest solution, you can try to change this method:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-safe-area